# Get json object from Result

Tags: playframework

is it possible to get json from created Result

I have a controller lets say

```
private static void doSth() {
    Result result = ok(json);
}
```

how to get json from result object? 
if its even possible ?

Comment: Improve your question please, i.e. tag it with proper versions and especially explain better what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example if you want to return a User object:

```
User user = new User("john");
return ok(Json.toJson(user));
```

Comment: in my experience when you want to do this you have to have an implicit formatter. In this case `implicit val myFormat = Json.format[User]`